# PHP: Need a opposite method of timezone_name_from_abbr?

Tags: php, timezone

I need an exactly opposite method of timezone_name_from_abbr(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php

I have a list of timezones name like:

```
Australia/Brisbane
Australia/Hobart
Asia/Vladivostok
Australia/Lord_Howe
Asia/Magadan
Asia/Kolkata
America/Los_Angeles
......
```

I need method which will take timezone as a param and return me a Abbreviation of it. For example:

If I use method like:

```
   $timeAbbr = timezone_abbr_from_name('America/Los_Angeles');
   echo $timeAbbr;
```

Result should be:

```
PST
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work.

```
function timezone_abbr_from_name($timezone_name){
    $dateTime = new DateTime(); 
    $dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone_name)); 
    return $dateTime->format('T'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DateTimeZone::ListAbbreviations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php) will give you an associative array with all long names related to a specific abbreviation. It should be fairly straightforward to build a function with this that returns the correct abbreviation. There is nothing ready-made in the User Contributed Notes as far as I can see.

Comment: Thnaks Pekka,

Its a great solution though but was looking for a straight forward code , (method). Thanks anyways, I can use your suggestion in other part of my project. 

Thank You.